# Linear Algebra Complex Numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

**The solutions to the equation $z^2-2z+2=0$ are $(a+i)$ and $(b-i)$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers.  What is $a+b$?**

I simplified and got $(z+1)(z+1) = -1$ and now I'm not sure where to go from there. I did this but I'm not sure.

$(a+i)^2 = a^2 - 1$

$(b-i)^2 = b^2 + 1$

$a+b=(a+i)+(b-i)=(a^2-1)+(b^2+1)=a^2+b^2$

Comment: We know that if $a+i$ is a root, then $a-i$ is a root. Hence $a=b$. Then, $(a-i)+(a+i) = 2$. Or $(a-i)(a+i) = 2$. Why? As for your algebra, $(a+bi)^2 = a^2 + 2abi + b^2i^2 = (a^2-b^2)+2abi \neq a + bi$. Just try $a=1$, $b$ arbitrary. I recommend reviewing the textbook.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a polynomial with real coefficients, $z$ is a root if and only if $\overline z$, the complex conjugate of $z$, is. Since $\overline{a + i} = a - i$, we see that $a = b$ necessarily.

Then using that $a + i$ and $a - i$ are roots, we can factor the polynomial as

\begin{align*}
z^2 + 2z + 2 &= \Big(z - (a + i)\Big)\Big(z - (a - i)\Big) \\
&= (z - a - i)(z - a + i) \\
&= (z - a)^2 - (i)^2 \\
&= z^2 - 2az + a^2 - 1
\end{align*}

Comparing coefficients, we see that $2 = -2a$ so that $a = -1$.

---

Fast way: By expanding $(z - \lambda)(z - \mu)$, we see that the product of the roots is the constant coefficient, and the sum of the roots is negative of the $z$-coefficient. Hence

$$a + b = \Big(a + i\Big) + \Big(b - i\Big) = -2$$

Comment: What happens if it was a-i and b-i?

Comment: @KarimB As a result of the first line of my answer, it *can't* be that.

Answer (score 2):

**Re: Your Work**
If you're going to solve this equation by factoring, etc., you do *not* want to factor and set equal to a non-zero number.  That is, doing something like:
$$(z+1)(z+1) = -1$$
does not point you in the right direction, because you can only find roots by factoring when you have the equation set equal to *zero*.

Also, please see Chris K's comments about the other parts of your algebra... in general, $(x+y)^2 \ne x^2 + y^2$.  That is, $(a+i)^2 \ne a^2 + i^2$.

**Re: The Problem Statement**
Because this is a quadratic with real coefficients, we know by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra that it will have exactly $2$ solutions, where complex solutions occur in *conjugate pairs.*

We are given that the two solutions are $a+i$ and $b-i$.  Since these are conjugate pairs, then $a=b$.

So, our two solutions are $a+i$ and $a-i$.  Having one variable makes things simpler.

We also know that 
$$\begin{align}
(z - (a+i))(z-(a-i)) &=z^2 + \left(-(a+i) - (a-i)\right)z + (a+i)(a-i) \\
&= z^2-2z+2
\end{align}$$

Equating coefficients, we find that $\left(-(a+i) - (a-i)\right) = -2$ and $(a+i)(a-i) = 2$.

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\,\ a\!+\!b = (a\!+\!i)+(b\!-\!i)\, =\, \color{#c00}{\rm sum\,\ of\,\ roots}.\,$ By [Vieta,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) this equals the negative of the coeff of $x$, explicitly $(x-\color{#c00}r)(x-\color{#c00}s)\, =\, x^2-(\color{#c00}{r\!+\!s})x+rs.$