# Complex numberss

Tags: linear-algebra

The solutions to the equation $x^2-(3-2i)x+(1-3i)=0$ are $a-i$ and $b-i$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers.  What is $a+b$?

$x^2-(3-2i)x+(1-3i) = (x+(a-i))(x-(a-i))$

$= x^2 - 2xi-a^2 - 1$

$1 = x^2 - 2xi - a^2$

I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: Vieta's formula says $$a-i+b-i=3-2i$$

Comment: You can solve this using the same methods as in the answers to the [previous question you asked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657927/linear-algebra-complex-numbers).

Answer (score 1):

a + b - 2i = (a - i) + (b - i) = sum of roots = -[-(3 - 2i)]

Therefore, a + b - 2i = 3 - 2i

Thus, a + b = 3

Answer (score 1):

Use the good, old, vanilla-flavored quadratic formula. Hint: It would certainly simplify matters if the imaginary part of the equation's discriminant were to vanish — which, happily, it does!